# ReadProcessMemory only works with breakpoint

Tags: c++, readprocessmemory

I start off creating a process, logging if it fails, and then a while loop to wait for the window to be found.

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION p;
STARTUPINFO s;
ZeroMemory(&s, sizeof(s));
s.cb = sizeof(s);
ZeroMemory(&p, sizeof(p));
if (!CreateProcessA("D:\\SteamLibrary\\steamapps\\common\\Fallout 4\\Wolf4SDL.exe", "", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &s, &p))
{
    _MESSAGE("CreateProcess failed (%d).", GetLastError());
}
//wait for the process to start
while (FindWindowA(NULL, "Wolfenstein 3D") == NULL);
```

Then set up the vars - x64 for both processes, so 64-bit addresses. "addr" is a pointer. addrOff is a static offset.

```
HANDLE procHandle = p.hProcess;
unsigned long long addr;
unsigned long long addrOff = 0x00000001401a7718;
SIZE_T NumberOfBytesToRead = sizeof(addr); 
SIZE_T NumberOfBytesActuallyRead;
```

Now the Read, and some basic debug messaging

```
ReadProcessMemory(procHandle, (LPCVOID)(addrOff), &addr, NumberOfBytesToRead, &NumberOfBytesActuallyRead);
_MESSAGE("addr: %p",addr);
_MESSAGE("numBytesRead: %d", NumberOfBytesActuallyRead);
```

So here's the issue - If I drop a breakpoint in this, `addr` will have the appropriate value for the static offset being read. If I do not, `addr` will have the value of 0x0000000000000000. In both cases, `NumberOfBytesActuallyRead` will have the appropriate value of 8. Which, even without looking at my log, the process is present and accounted for - but looking at my log confirms this.

Needless to say, this makes debugging this issue damn near impossible. Now, one oddity came to mind - I've noticed in examples where people add the offset to the base address, while I'm just using the offset. So, with the possibility that my value of `addrOff` includes the base address, I checked the base address in both situations - and they were both the same. And for the sake of completion, the base address code.

```
unsigned long long dwBase = -1;

EnumProcessModules(procHandle, hModules, 0, &cModules);
hModules = new HMODULE[cModules / sizeof(HMODULE)];

if (EnumProcessModules(procHandle, hModules, cModules / sizeof(HMODULE), &cModules)) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < cModules / sizeof(HMODULE); i++) {
        if (GetModuleBaseName(procHandle, hModules[i], szBuf, sizeof(szBuf))) {
            if (std::string("Wolf4SDL.exe").compare(szBuf) == 0) {
                dwBase = (unsigned long long)hModules[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's caused by the extra time delay you create when you use a breakpoint? What if ReadProcessMemory runs but the address isn't stored in memory yet?

Comment: @user253751 I really should've thought about that - I assumed that if the window was there, that everything else static would be. But, sure enough, initializing addr to 0, and enclosing ReadProcessMemory in a while loop, while it still equaled zero, seems to have done the trick. If you make it an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.

The variable you are reading is still 0 when you read it.

When you use a breakpoint, the time delay where you look at the code and press continue is when the other process sets the variable.